# R dataframe: replace first value (one column) by each group (other column)

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I want to convert `have` to `want` (please see below). Specifically, I want to change the first value (`have$b`) for each group (`have$a)` to a common value (here: zero).

```
have <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,2,3,3,3), b=c(-5, -3, 2, -2, 6, 2))

want <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,2,3,3,3), b=c(0, 0, 2, 0, 6, 2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the other answers, I wanted to give this base `R` approach:

```
have$b[ c(1, diff(have$a))==1 ] <- 0
```

which also gives:

```
  a b
1 1 0
2 2 0
3 2 2
4 3 0
5 3 6
6 3 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` approach could be

```r
library(dplyr)

have %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(b = case_when(row_number() == 1 ~ 0,    #replace 1st row value of each group to 0
                       TRUE ~ b))
```

which gives

```
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  1.00  0   
2  2.00  0   
3  2.00  2.00
4  3.00  0   
5  3.00  6.00
6  3.00  2.00
```

**Sample data:**

```
have <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), b = c(-5, -3, 2, -2, 
6, 2)), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need a way of establishing a grouping variable and getting the row number within the group. This can be done with `data.table` pretty easily.

```
library(data.table)
have <- data.table(a=c(1,2,2,3,3,3), b=c(-5, -3, 2, -2, 6, 2))
```

In `data.table` there is more than just the row/column indexes. The second argument is actually where we can mutate columns (`id := 1:.N`) and the third argument is a grouping argument (`by = a`). In the second argument `:=` means to replace inline and the `.N` is the number of rows in each group.

```
have[,id := 1:.N, by=`a`]
#>    a  b id
#> 1: 1 -5  1
#> 2: 2 -3  1
#> 3: 2  2  2
#> 4: 3 -2  1
#> 5: 3  6  2
#> 6: 3  2  3
```

Note how the `id` column is counting the rows in each group of `a`. Now you want to replace `b` with 0 where `id == 1`. Here the first index will filter the rows and the second argument assigns a value to `b`, but only where the filter condition is met.

```
have[id == 1, b := 0]
#>    a b id
#> 1: 1 0  1
#> 2: 2 0  1
#> 3: 2 2  2
#> 4: 3 0  1
#> 5: 3 6  2
#> 6: 3 2  3
```

Finally, you could remove the extra `id` column by assigning it null.

```
have[,id := NULL]
```